# ESP32 AsyncWebServer combined with WifiClient communicating with same IP address

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

My setup is as follows. An ESP32 devkit and a Sonos music player. The idea is to control the Sonos box, using a WiFiClient. With the ESP32 and its connected buttons, I send commands to the Sonos, to play a certain music file, set the volume and many other things. Works well.

The music files are just urls that direct the Sonos to fetch the music file from.

The next step was to add an SD card to my ESP32 and store musicfiles on the SD. I used ESPAsyncWebser, and I can retrieve the music files from my ESP32. Sonos plays them perfectly.

It's the combination that fails sometimes. While the asyncwebserver does it's job and sends out the music data, and the ESP talking to the same Sonos to change volume or add a song to the playlist/queue, it sometimes hangs just there, and the WifiClient is not able to connect or reconnect anymore, and no more music data is sent out. The ESP32 does not really crash, it still functions, the buttons keep working etcetera.

My WifiClient only connects to port 1400 on the Sonos. The Sonos gets the music from the webserver at port 80.

The bare question is, is it even possible to use WiFiClient objects together with the ESPAsyncWebServer when both are connected to the same IP address (the Sonos box) ?

Thanks in advance for any pointers ;-)

Comment: yes it is possible. you have it working.

Comment: Well, point taken ;-) But I have a feeling that deep down in the catacombes these two clash when they cross each other. For now, I am moving my Sonos commands to a async websocket, which is build upon the same asyncTCP that the webserver uses. Too early to say that is the solution, but it seems to become a bit more stable. Hope it solves my lockups once I moved everything....